# How to implement TabHost with the ability to use multiple activities under a tab?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

As the title says, I want to know how to implement TabHost with the ability to switch between activities under a tab.Simple example would be to have two tabs(tab1 & tab2) with a button under tab1. when this button is clicked, a text appears.
(activity switch)

A google search suggested using GroupActivities, but upon further searching I came to know that this is deprecated.
So would appreciate any help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

you can find more help here...
http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabsFragment.html

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. And prefer answers linked to the question at hand, what you are suggesting is about Fragments and OP is asking about activities...